# Is there a pretty way to split in IEnumerable into 2 groups like this?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a piece of code like

```
var inserts = viewtags.Where(vt => vt.TagID == null);
var updates = viewtags.Where(vt => vt.TagID != null);
```

but I'm wondering whether there's a better way to partition an IEnumerable into 2 mutually exclusive groups?

Comment: `var groups = viewtags.GroupBy(vt => vt.TagID != null);`

Comment: Did you mean GroupBy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Linq [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx). You can do this using the following:

```
var results = viewtags.GroupBy(vt => vt.TagID != null);
```

Obviously I don't actually know the class of your `vt` items in this case. But this will essentially return an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Bool, VTClass>>` that you can then operate on. If you want to access the items based on whether you need to do inserts or updates, then a better way is to call [ToLookup()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var results = viewtags.ToLookup(vt => vt.TagID != null);
```

At this point you can do, which makes it slightly easier to consume for later:

```
var inserts = results[false];
var updates = results[true];
```

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but if you are going to use it that way, you'd better use `ToLookup` rather than `GroupBy` + `ToDictionary`, which also will prevent `KeyNotFoundException` in the last 2 lines.